# How can I get the process id for the same query I have executed on postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pid

I have executed some query from my remote PostgreSQL database with the help of a simple jdbc java program for which I want process Id. Can anyone suggest how can I get the process id for the same query I have executed?

Comment: Which process id? From the Java process, of the PostgreSQL connection process or something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The process ID is assigned when you open the connection to the database server. 
It's per connection, **not** an ID "per query"!

So before you run your actual query, you can run:

```
select pg_backend_pid();
```

to the get the PID assigned to your JDBC connection. Then you can e.g. log it or print it somehow so that you know it once your query is running.